# problema con try catch

Tags: php, html

Ando haciendo un login que me valide los usuarios pero tengo problemas con el try catch y no se a que se deba.

Mi código es como sigue:

```
<?php
try{
$base=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=trabajofinal" , "root", "");
$base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sql="SELECT * FROM usuarios=  WHERE usuarios=:login AND password= :password";
$resultado=$base->prepare($sql);
$login=htmlentities(addcslashes($_POST["login"]));
$password=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["password"]));
$resultado->bindValue(":login", $login);
$resultado->bindValue(":password", $password);

$resultado->execute(); //ejecuta la consulta


$id=$resultado->rowCount(); //devuelve 0 y 1 y lo guarda


if($id!=0){
    session_start(); //crea sesion al usuario y la almacena

    $_SESSION['usuario']=$_POST['login'];

    header("location:usuarioslogiados.php");

}else{
    header("location:logincorregido.php");

    }
    catch(Exception $e){
throw new Exception('direccion no encontrada');

}

finally
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En la sección

```
}else{
    header("location:logincorregido.php");

    }
    catch(Exception $e){
```

te falta un corchete para cerrar el `try`. El que hay cierra el `else`.